# Tuleap new project error

Tags: tuleap

On new project registration the following error is received:
*Invalid Short Name
test1 is already reserved for another rename operation. Please check     System Event Monitor.*

This happens regardless of what shortname is given to the project.
The Tuleap version is 8.4.99.22. runing on CenotOs 6. The event monitor is empty.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the list of projects **and** the list of users. Both lists are used to determine if a shortname is reserved or not.

The other possibilities that would prevent the project to be created:

- the shortname already exists on file system in service directories (`find /var/lib/tuleap -name "test1"` and `find /home -name "test1"`)
- there is no space left on partitions for /var/lib or /home
- selinux or like

**EDIT (from comments)**:
- inspect system_events tables to look at suspicious events: `select id, type, status, parameters from system_event where type in ('PROJECT_RENAME', 'USER_RENAME');`

Comment: Thanks, but all of these look fine. - the shortname doesnt exist in any directory. I have tried countless short names (even gibberish) and always the same error message. There is lots of disk space - all partitions are less then 30% usage. I haven't configured selinux so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: What is the result of `select id, type, status, parameters from system_event where type in ('PROJECT_RENAME', 'USER_RENAME');` ?

Comment: Thanks very much for the direction. I found that the mysql table  "system_event" was corrupted and I repaired it using mysqlcheck. Now I can create new projects without any problem.